# Is there a way to search for a string in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want a code that searches a html for a given string. The problem is that I don't have anything in my html file as you can see below. I only have script that displays RSS on my page. I need code that does this after my RSS is displayed.

I tried this code :

```
if (
   document.getElementById('ElementName').innerHTML.indexOf('Text to search for') != -1) {
  alert("FOUND!");
} else {
  alert("NOT FOUND!");
}
```

But it doesnt work.

```
<!-- MY HTML BELOW -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset ="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
            <div class="weather" style="margin-top: 10%;">
                <script language="JavaScript" src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fmeteoalarm.eu%2Fdocuments%2Frss%2Frs%2FRS003.rss&chan=y&utf=y&html=a"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <noscript>
                    <a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fmeteoalarm.eu%2Fdocuments%2Frss%2Frs%2FRS003.rss&chan=y&utf=y&html=y">View RSS feed</a>
                </noscript>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You've tagged both JS and PHP. Are you looking for a JS or PHP solution?

Comment: Possibly looking at a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: I tagged both of them because i'm looking for a working solution.  I prefer JS, but maybe there is a better solution with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (
   document.documentElement.innerHTML.search('Text to search for') != -1) {
  alert("FOUND!");
} else {
  alert("NOT FOUND!");
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will have an explanation of what is done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Whatever I put in "text to search for", it always says "FOUND!" .